# Concatenate to nil should return nil in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, string-concatenation

I need to produce a string surrounded by parenthesis but only if its value is not empty. Currently I'm using something similar to:

```
[5] pry(main)> a = nil
=> nil
[6] pry(main)> a.nil? ? '' : "(#{a})"
=> ""
[7] pry(main)> a = "world"
=> "world"
[8] pry(main)> a.nil? ? '' : "(#{a})"
=> "(world)"
```

But I consider it to be repetitive. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Just FYI `a.nil?` returns false for an empty string, you probably want a.blank?

Comment: @Mark `.blank?` is an ActiveSupport method and this is not tagged as a rails question.

Comment: @max Good point.

Comment: ``.blank?`` isn't core Ruby, but its implementation is instructive: ``respond_to?(:empty?) ? !!empty? : !self``

Answer (score 3):

You could just write a method that does this:

```
def bracketize(str)
  return '' unless (str)
  "(#{str})"
end
```

As that makes it clear what you're doing and you don't have to stamp this code all over the place.

Comment: Nitpicking: wouldn't `parenthesize` be more appropriate (but harder to spell)?

Comment: @muistooshort `add_round_grabby_things_around_some_text`

Comment: Maybe something longer and more descriptive would be better ;)

Comment: This is ok, however doesn't answer my 'is there a simpler way' question, given that just creating a method for the same logic is not what I was asking. Giving you useful vote, though. I was trying to find a different method (the only one that comes to mind is the + vs & function in Visual Basic that propagates empties or nulls into the concatenation.

Comment: The simpler way is to write a method. The even simpler way is to make this method more broadly accessible, like define it on `NilClass` and `String` so you can do `s.bracketize` or whatever you prefer for a name. Ruby is flexible and allows altering core classes in whatever method you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

Just put your code in a method:

```
def parentheses(a=nil)
  a.nil? ? '' : "(#{a})"  
end
```